# Cut-out text with CSS

Tags: html, css, button, styles

I try to create a hover effect for a button in CSS.
[image: How it should look like finished]

Basically text should be 'cut out' of its parent element, making it see-through to the sites background.
I'd do the stripes with a gradient, but my problem is to add transparency to the font.
I looked at background-clip, but that would do the opposite of what I try to achieve, and would make things way more complicated. 
Is there an easy way to accomplish this effect? I don't mind using JS, but no jQuery if possible.

Comment: CSS cannot do that yet, maybe webkit where you can use an image using text as a mask, the idea would be to use svg for newer browser see http://nimbupani.com/using-background-clip-for-text-with-css-fallback.html and so http://lea.verou.me/2012/05/text-masking-the-standards-way/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to follow my comment and links within , using svg , you can get this kind of things :
http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Dqcio/

```
svg {
  position:absolute;
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg,
    transparent,
    transparent 5px,
    black 5px,
    black 10px
    );
  width:600px;
  height:300px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-clip: content-box; 
  padding:60px 70px;
}
text {
  font-size:8em;
  fill:url(#textpattern);
  stroke: white;
  border:solid;
  }
div {
  position:relative;
  width:600px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

and markup :

```
    <div>
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <pattern id="textpattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="600" height="300" >
        <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/nature/9" width="600" height="300"  x="-70px" y="-60px"/>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <text  y="120px" x="140px">test </text>
  </svg>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/nature/9" />
</div>
```

With CSS , you can even add transparent borders and radius to make it look weirder http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wsfvg/

Comment: this works with my latest version of : Firefox, Opera, Safari,Internet Explorer , Chrome , under w7

Answer (score 4):

In my example below, I'm using CSS [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) with a blend mode of `difference`.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:900,600,500,800,700);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
}
div {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  width:100%;
}
h1 {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #9c9c9c;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 10vw;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9674/isolation-destination.jpg" alt="" />
  <h1>Let the sun shine!</h1>
</div>
```

[View on CodePen](http://codepen.io/SaraSoueidan/pen/887433527fac4e926e84b613be483bfc?editors=110)
[View my blog post on compositing and blending](https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/compositing-and-blending-in-css/)

Comment: Just linking to your own library (or utility) or someone else's is not a good answer. In fact it is considered Not An Answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code using it to do so and disclaiming makes for a good answer. See: [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/)

Comment: It was my first time answering a question... Thank you for the feedback, I'll try to do better in the future!

Comment: This doesn't work in Linux Mint Firefox. It works in Chrome, though. Brilliant effect, though.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode - No Edge or IE.  Partial Safari

Answer (score -1):

Try using Photoshop to create text with just outline and no background color then save it in a .png format then place that text inside div and decorate this div with gradient.
hope this helps in someway

Check Following Image Created in Photoshop.......
[image: this is a PNG Image...]

Comment: Not to be rude, but it is 2014 and I would never, never, ever again use photoshop for things like these. Apart from that, this would still not work and only make the text transparent, but not cut it out of the parents background.

Comment: Yeah i know Photoshop is really time consuming but it can help you in getting the result you want. Check my new editted answer:). Hope That helps you in some way..