# How to create buttons with semi transparent background with completely transparent text?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have semitransparent buttons with fully transparent text on them. If I set text color to say #00FFFFFF and background to #33FFFFFF the text portion isn't transparent and shows background. The text has to be dynamic so I can't use an image.

Comment: why cant you set a image for background?

Comment: @Sree Because the text has to be dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this is what you are trying to achieve(works with background color, not with background image)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#f00"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#88000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TEXT TO TRANSPARENT"
    android:textColor="#f00" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Create a new layout file, paste the above code and click the layout "preview" button to check how it looks like.

OR

Check this link
    [Button with background color and transparent text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956575/button-with-background-color-and-transparent-text?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are not setting the background color of button as it supposed to be... try #07000000 for button backgroun

Comment: Sorry, but then the font also takes the color #07000000 when its supposed to be #00000000. Thanks for help